# AutoDictionary for objects with a key property

Tags: c#, hash-map

The *normal* dictiory separates the key from the value... but what if the key is a part of the item it stores? It then forces you to enter the same things twice, once for the key and agian for the item. I never liked it so I thought I write really simple class that takes this unecessary step away a makes life easier again by allowing you to specify a key selector like the `ToDictionary` extension does.

```
public class AutoDictionary<TKey, TItem> : ICollection<TItem>, IEnumerable<TItem>
{
    private readonly Func<TItem, TKey> _keySelector;

    private readonly IDictionary<TKey, TItem> _items;

    public AutoDictionary(Func<TItem, TKey> keySelector)
    {
        _keySelector = keySelector;
        _items = new Dictionary<TKey, TItem>();
    }

    public AutoDictionary(Func<TItem, TKey> keySelector, IEqualityComparer<TKey> equalityComparer)
    : this(keySelector)
    {
        _items = new Dictionary<TKey, TItem>(equalityComparer);
    }

    public AutoDictionary(Func<TItem, TKey> keySelector, IDictionary<TKey, TItem> other)
    : this(keySelector)
    {
        _keySelector = keySelector;
        _items = new Dictionary<TKey, TItem>(other);
    }

    public TItem this[TKey key]
    {
        get { return _items[key]; }
        set { _items[key] = value; }
    }

    public int Count => _items.Count;

    public bool IsReadOnly => false;

    public void Add(TItem item) => _items.Add(_keySelector(item), item);

    public void Clear() => _items.Clear();

    public bool TryGetItem(TKey key, out TItem item) => _items.TryGetValue(key, out item);

    public bool Contains(TItem item) => _items.ContainsKey(_keySelector(item));

    public void CopyTo(TItem[] array, int arrayIndex) { }

    public bool Remove(TItem item) => _items.Remove(_keySelector(item));

    public IEnumerator<TItem> GetEnumerator() => _items.Values.GetEnumerator();

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => GetEnumerator();
}
```

*I wanted to make all methods use lambdas but the constructor doesn't allow this :-(*

---

Usage:

```
class Foo
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Bar { get; set;}
    public double Baz { get; set;}
}

var autoDic = new AutoDictionary<string, Foo>(x => x.Name)
{
    new Foo { Name = "foo1", Bar = 1 },
    new Foo { Name = "foo2", Bar = 2 },
    //new Foo { Name = "foo1", Bar = 1 }, // bam!
};

var foo1 = autoDic["foo1"];
```

*I guess I've reinvented the wheel, haven't I? ;-)*

Comment: Doesn't look like re-inventing the wheel. Looks more like specializing a wheel.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The single most surprising thing that jumps at me is that an `AutoDictionary` doesn't implement [`IDictionary`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.idictionary(v=vs.110).aspx), and therefore can't be used as such. This is a rather major oversight, enough to be a showstopper in deciding whether or not I would use this data structure or not.

Short of implementing and exposing an [`Add(object, object)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.idictionary.add(v=vs.110).aspx) method, this `AutoDictionary` is simply not a *dictionary* as far as client code is concerned - it's a [keyed] *collection*, or an *enumerable*, but not a *dictionary*.

I would definitely try to find a way to implement the generic [`IDictionary<TKey,TValue>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s4ys34ea(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1) interface *on top of* `IDictionary`, too.

How? Well you already have a `TKey` generic type parameter, so a generic dictionary implementation would definitely be easy. The non-generic interface could validate the type of the key parameter (e.g. the first `object` in the `Add(object, object)` method) and throw some `ArgumentException` if the type can't be cast to `TKey`.

I'd also add a constructor that intakes the `IDictionary` dependency:

```
public AutoDictionary(IDictionary<TKey, TItem> source, Func<TItem, TKey> keySelector)
    : this(keySelector)
{
    _items = source;
}
```

Accepting a generic dictionary constrained with `TKey` would make the `_items` assignment compile and guaranteed to work, but would would still need to validate that the existing keys are those returned by the `keySelector`, and throw an exception otherwise.

Why is the second generic type parameter named `TItem`, when every `IDictionary` reference in the framework names it `TValue`? That's another rather surprising detail.

---

This is bad:

> ```
> public void CopyTo(TItem[] array, int arrayIndex) { }
> ```

The method should *at least* throw a `NotImplementedException`. This no-op member is part of the interface, the *contract* you've signed when you decided to implement it: IMO leaving it unimplemented breaks the *Liskov Substitution Principle*, which means your implementation *cannot* be used in place of any other `ICollection` implementation. It should populate the `array` parameter with all values in stored in `_items`.

---

The class isn't `sealed`, which means a new class could be derived from it. Consider implementing the interface members as `virtual`, so their implementation could be overridden in inherited types - or outright seal the class.

Comment: I cannot implement the `IDictionary` interface because it requires the `KeyValuePair` struct via the `ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>` that is the problem. It's harcoded for this interface and you cannot override it. I has always bothered me in the .net that the dictionary is treated like a holy grail that cannot have any other implementation whatsoever :-( the same for the `Value` property. It's one of the most usless properties in .net that always comes inbetween the dictionary and the item especially if the item is an object.

Comment: As to `CopyTo` - I really forgot to implement it as I have never ever used it before ;-)

Comment: I prefer to use a dictionary like `dic["foo1"].Bar` rahter then `Dic["foo1"].Value.Bar`. Why is the value there? It doesn't help in any way.

Comment: Then IMO what you have is more like a `ISet<T>` and the class name is misleading; the key is merely used as an index. What if one wanted to iterate the keys?

Comment: `Dic["foo1"]` doesn't return a KVP AFAIK... and you can definitely implement `ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>` *on top* of `ICollection<TValue>` - make it an explicit interface implementation if you don't want to expose these members directly.

Comment: Well, there isn't really a good name for it but it's a pity that the dictionary doesn't allow to exchange the KVP. You're right, by bad, it wasn't a good usage example. However you have the KVP problem in a loop when the element is a KVP or when adding elements you need to write `.Add(item.SomeProperty, item)` or `dic[item.SomeProperty] = item`... oh I see I need to remove the setter or better override the `+` operator.

Comment: One more thing: `IDictionary` requires the `Add(TKey key, TValue value)` method but at this point there is no way to guarantee that the key actually comes from the value. I could ignore it and use the key-selector anyway but it wouldn't be right too. I think it will have to stay a workaround for the _defect_ dictionary with the hardcoded KVP struct. I'll just change the name into keyed-collection or something similar.

Comment: @t3chb0t I would reuse the validation method I mentioned the `AutoDictionary(IDictionary<TKey, TItem> source, Func<TItem, TKey> keySelector)` constructor overload would use, and throw the same exception if the `key` mismatches the value returned by the `_keySelector` for the specified `value`.

Comment: This becomes more and more interesting ;-) _operator != cannot be applied to TKey and TKey_ when I try to `key != _keySelector(value)` I'll need to take a look into their source code how they do it.